# Finding the peaks of an array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, graph

I have an array of 640 values that contains the y-values of what is needed to draw a line.

[image: Line]

I need to determine array positions of the tops of each three peaks.

I have looked at similar questions on here relating to local maxima/local minima, but running the code I have found picks up the small peaks. I only need the three very distinct peaks.

I am trying to do this in Javascript. The data from the array is as follows:

```
126,126,126,126,126,126,126,126,126,126,126,126,126,126,124,123,122,122,120,119,119,118,118,118,119,119,119,120,121,121,122,124,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,124,125,124,125,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,124,123,124,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,122,123,122,123,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,121,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,119,119,119,119,116,115,114,113,113,113,113,113,115,117,118,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,119,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,118,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,117,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,114,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,110,108,107,106,118,108,108,103,103,103,103,103,103,104,105,107,108,109,109,109,109,109,109,109,109,109,109,109,109,109,109,109
```

I ran this bit of code on the array:

```
    function pickPeaks(arr){
  return arr.reduce( (res, val, i, self) => {
    if(
      // a peak when the value is greater than the previous and greater than the next
      val > self[i - 1] && val > self[i + 1] 
      || 
      // a plateau when the value is greater than the previuos and equal to the next and from there the next different value is less
      val > self[i - 1] && val === self[i + 1] && self.slice(i).find( item =>  item !== val ) < val 
    ){
      res.pos.push(i);
      res.peaks.push(val);
    }
    return res;
  }, { pos:[],peaks:[] } );
}

console.log(pickPeaks(first_black_array))
```

and it outputted the following:

```
peaks: (9) [362, 356, 356, 357, 358, 358, 367, 374, 377]
pos: (9) [21, 67, 69, 112, 179, 181, 313, 608, 612]
```

I would like the results to be something like:

```
pos: [24, 316, 616]
```

(the tops of each of the peaks)

Many thanks

Comment: "I am trying to do this in Javascript." What have you tried exactly?

Comment: what do you mean by 3 distinct peaks? as in if 126 was peak earlier dont consider it ?

Comment: You could run a window over the values, calculate the sum of differences between the values in the window and see where there is more change than a given threshold. Those would be the peaks in data like yours.

Comment: I have tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42565092/1674937 and it outputs the following: peaks: (9) [362, 356, 356, 357, 358, 358, 367, 374, 377]
pos: (9) [21, 67, 69, 112, 179, 181, 313, 608, 612]

Comment: please add the result as well.

Comment: So which three numbers would you expect to get back here for your specific example? _“I only need the three very distinct peaks”_ - well then start thinking about how “very distinct” could be expressed _mathematically_, because right now that is just very vague prose.

Comment: I have edited the question to show what I have tried, the results and my expected result

Comment: Can you explain your data more thoroughly? I don't know where you got your peak numbers from. Your array contains 24 unique values between 103 and 126 ?

Comment: By peaks I mean the tops of the three bumps on the image. I've seen it referred to as local maxima, but I'm not sure if this is what is SHOULD be called

Comment: Can you define a threshold for noticeable peak?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on my comment, something like

```
function detectPeaks(data, windowWidth, threshold) {
  const peaks = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const start = Math.max(0, i - windowWidth);
    const end = Math.min(data.length, i + windowWidth);
    let deltaAcc = 0;
    for (let a = start; a < end; a++) {
      deltaAcc += Math.abs(data[a - 1] - data[a]);
    }
    if (deltaAcc > threshold) {
      peaks.push(i);
    }
  }
  return peaks;
}
```

does reasonably well to find the "peaks" (or rather, areas where there are more change in values than elsewhere).

You can find an interactive example at https://codepen.io/akx/pen/QowEQq where you can also tweak the window width and threshold values.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. From this I should be able to modify the output so that it shows the centre value of each instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could look for smaller values, in comparison to the previous value and by updating the index of the last smallest value and if the values are increasing, then push the new minima.

Actually this approach returns a minima at index 608 where is should no, according to the question. Maybe you need to filter too small deltas of minima.

```js
var data = [126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 124, 123, 122, 122, 120, 119, 119, 118, 118, 118, 119, 119, 119, 120, 121, 121, 122, 124, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 124, 125, 124, 125, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 123, 124, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 122, 123, 122, 123, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 119, 119, 119, 119, 116, 115, 114, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 115, 117, 118, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 108, 107, 106, 118, 108, 108, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 104, 105, 107, 108, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109],
    push = true,
    last = 0,
    result = data.reduce((r, v, i, a) => {
        if (a[r[last]] === v) {                  // take latest index of series
            r[last] = i;
            return r;
        }
        if (a[i - 1] < v) {                      // look for new series
            push = true;
            return r;
        }
        if (a[i - 1] > v) {
            if (push && a[i - 1] > a[r[last]]) { // prevent continuing minima
                last = r.push(i) - 1;
                push = false;
            } else {
                r[last] = i;
            }
        }
        return r;
    }, []);


console.log('values ', result.map(i => data[i].toString().padStart(3)).join(' '));
console.log('indices', result.map(v => v.toString().padStart(3)).join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will go through your data and determine the largest transitions in data. It will then coordinate them so that the same peak will not be output to you when grabbing `n` records.

```
   function getPeaks(data, n = 3, peakList = []) {
      return data.reduce((a, v, i, _a,
          end_index = _a.length - 1,
          change = v - _a[i - 1] || 0,
          mate = i + Math.sign(change),
          _ = (change) && a.peaks.push({change,i,mate})
        ) => (i === end_index) ?
        (a.peaks.forEach(_ =>
            (!peakList.includes(_.i) && (mate = a.peaks.find(__ =>
              __.i === _.mate))) && (a.samePeak.push({
              highpoint: data[_.i] > data[mate.i] ? _.i : mate.i,
              steepness: mate.change > _.change ? mate.change : _.change
            })),
            peakList.push(_.i, mate.i)),
          a.samePeak.sort((_, __) =>
            __.steepness - _.steepness)
          .map(_ => _.highpoint)
          .slice(0, n)) : a, {
          peaks: [],
          samePeak: []
        })
    }
```

```js
let data = [126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 124, 123, 122, 122, 120, 119, 119, 118, 118, 118, 119, 119, 119, 120, 121, 121, 122, 124, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 124, 125, 124, 125, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 123, 124, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 122, 123, 122, 123, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 119, 119, 119, 119, 116, 115, 114, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 115, 117, 118, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 108, 107, 106, 118, 108, 108, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 104, 105, 107, 108, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109]


function getPeaks(data, n = 3, peakList = []) {
  return data.reduce((a, v, i, _a,
      end_index = _a.length - 1,
      change = v - _a[i - 1] || 0,
      mate = i + Math.sign(change),
      _ = (change) && a.peaks.push({
        change,
        i,
        mate
      })
    ) => (i === end_index) ?
    (a.peaks.forEach(_ =>
        (!peakList.includes(_.i) && (mate = a.peaks.find(__ =>
          __.i === _.mate))) && (a.samePeak.push({
          highpoint: data[_.i] > data[mate.i] ? _.i : mate.i,
          steepness: mate.change > _.change ? mate.change : _.change
        })),
        peakList.push(_.i, mate.i)),
      a.samePeak.sort((_, __) =>
        __.steepness - _.steepness)
      .map(_ => _.highpoint)
      .slice(0, n)) : a, {
      peaks: [],
      samePeak: []
    })
}

//getpeaks(data, number of peaks to get)

console.log( getPeaks(data, 3) );
```

---

**Admittedly,** it became a little obfuscated as I went through - :) Here's a clearer version:

```
function getPeaks(data, n = 3, peakList = [] ) {
    return data.reduce( ( a, v, i, _a, end_index = _a.length - 1 ) => {
        change = v - _a[ i - 1 ] || 0,
            mate = i + Math.sign( change ),
            payload = {
                change,
                i,
                mate
            };
        if ( change ) a.peaks.push( payload );
        return ( i === end_index ) ? ( a.peaks.forEach( _ => {
            if ( peakList.includes( _.i ) ) return;
            if ( mate = a.peaks.find( __ => __.i === _.mate ) ) {
                a.samePeak.push( {
                        highpoint: data[ _.i ] > data[ mate.i ] ? _.i : mate.i,
                        steepness: mate.change > _.change ? mate.change : _.change
                } )
                peakList.push( _.i, mate.i );
            }
        } ), a ) : a;
    }, {
        peaks: [],
        samePeak: []
    } ).samePeak.sort( ( _, __ ) => __.steepness - _.steepness )
  .map(({highpoint})=>highpoint)
  .slice( 0, n );
}
```

```js
    function getPeaks(data, n = 3, peakList = [] ) {
     return data.reduce( ( a, v, i, _a, end_index = _a.length - 1 ) => {
      change = v - _a[ i - 1 ] || 0,
       mate = i + Math.sign( change ),
       payload = {
        change,
        i,
        mate
       };
      if ( change ) a.peaks.push( payload );
      return ( i === end_index ) ? ( a.peaks.forEach( _ => {
       if ( peakList.includes( _.i ) ) return;
       if ( mate = a.peaks.find( __ => __.i === _.mate ) ) {
        a.samePeak.push( {
          highpoint: data[ _.i ] > data[ mate.i ] ? _.i : mate.i,
          steepness: mate.change > _.change ? mate.change : _.change
        } )
        peakList.push( _.i, mate.i );
       }
      } ), a ) : a;
     }, {
      peaks: [],
      samePeak: []
     } ).samePeak.sort( ( _, __ ) => __.steepness - _.steepness )
      .map(({highpoint})=>highpoint)
      .slice( 0, n );
    }

console.log( getPeaks(data, 3) );
```